# How can I get total sum of every customers paid amount in Laravel ??

Tags: mysql, laravel, database, eloquent, calculated-columns

I'm trying to get highest paid amount from my laravel app. From my payments table I want to use customer_id & paid_amount for calculating hightest paid amount but my code isn't working expected! please see my code snippet below

**N.B: I want to get all columns of payments table, but how I can do that?**

```
$payments = Payment::with(['customer'])
                        ->select(DB::raw('sum(paid_amount) as paid_amount, customer_id'))
                        ->orderBy('customer_id', 'DESC')
                        ->paginate(10);
```

Also I've tried this one but this times it shows me an error because I was using relations with Customer model!

```
$payments = Payment::select(DB::raw('sum(paid_amount) as paid_amount, customer_id'))
                        ->groupBy('customer_id')
                        ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Can you share your Table structure?

Comment: Please don't vandalise your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the query this way to get SUM.

```
Payment::query()
->select(DB::raw("sum(paid_amount) as paid_amount, customer_id"))
->with(['customer'])
->groupBy('customer_id')
->orderBy('customer_id', 'DESC')
->get();
```

Comment: Do you want sum of other columns? As per your screenshot which columns do you want to add?

Comment: You can't do it like this if you want group by with only customer id. Let me know Do you want the listing of data by customer or by payment ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution if you want to do it with pagination and relationship.

```
Payment::query()
->select(DB::raw("sum(paid_amount) as paid_amount, customer_id"))
->with(['customer'])
->groupBy('customer_id')
->orderBy('customer_id', 'DESC')
->paginate(10)
```

Comment: Thanks! @AsfandyarKhan, but I want to get other columns along with paid_amount & customer_id, how i can do that??

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
Payment::select(DB::raw("sum(payments.paid_amount) as paid_amount"), payments.customer_id")
->join('customers','payments.customer_id','=','customers.id')
->groupBy('payments.customer_id')
->orderBy('payments.customer_id', 'DESC')
->paginate(10);
```